# Eigenvalue and eigenvector to compute

Tags: matrices

Find $A^ {20} X$

$A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix with the following eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

$V_1 =[1,0,0]\ldots V_2 =[1,1,0]\ldots V_3 =[1,1,1]$

corresponding to Eigenvalues..

λ1=−1/3,λ2=1/3,λ3=1

$X=[2,1,2]$

First we write X as a linear combination of $V_1 ,V_2 ,V_3$
V1,V2,V3
:

I don't know how to process and formula their use >>> follow text box X=1V 1 −1V 2 +2V 3

And how to compute A20x

Answer (score 1):

HINTS

$$X=1V_1 −1V_2 +2V_3$$

Multiply $A$ both sides
$$AX=AV_1 −AV_2 +2AV_3$$

Since $V_i$ are eigenvectors, $AV_i = \lambda_iV_i$:
$$AX=\lambda_1V_1 −\lambda_2V_2 +2\lambda_3V_3$$

Keep multiplying $A$ both sides for $19$ more times and get
$$A^{20}X={\lambda_1}^{20}V_1 −{\lambda_2}^{20}V_2 +2{\lambda_3}^{20}V_3$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compute $A^{20}X$.

Hint: for $i=1,2,3$ we have $AV_i=\lambda_i^{20}V_i$.

Can you proceed ?